# Firebase - Multiple Projects (dev and prod) same app target

Tags: ios, firebase, firebase-analytics

I'm looking at Firebase documentation on how to achieve this ([see here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/configure/)). Here is the instruction:

`If the builds are part of a single target, the best option is to give both configuration files unique names (e.g. GoogleService-Info-Free.plist and GoogleService-Info-Paid.plist). Then choose at runtime which plist to load.`

However, at the end of the page, there is "caveat" to this implementation:

`On iOS, do not add GoogleService-Info.plist to your project if you are supplying different configuration at run time, as this can result in an apparent change of GOOGLE_APP_ID and result in lost Analytics.`

Since I'm trying to add multiple environments to an existing app (live in the App Store) that has a `GoogleService-Info.plist` added to its project, does that mean I cannot do that since it will result in lost Analytics? Or, can I simply remove the `GoogleService-Info.plist` and add the environment specific ones, without any problems?

Answer (score 0):

The GoogleService-Info.plist is recommended since it allows Analytics to report early events. If you configure it at run-time, says switching from Google App ID A to B, then you will lose events of A logged before configuring with B. It's more like a warning to let you know the risk of using the runtime API.